# Closed simple curve and curl of function

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Let $F: \mathbb R^3\setminus \{0\} \to \mathbb R^3$. Prove that if $\operatorname{curl}(F)=0$, then the integral $\int_C F\cdot ds=0$ for every simple closed curve $C$. Is this statement true for $F:\mathbb R^2 \setminus \{0\} \to \mathbb R^2$?

I've read the proof of this theorem in Tromba's textbook for a vector field defined in $\mathbb R^3$. The theorem holds in this case for $F$ defined in all $\mathbb R^3$ except perhaps at a finite number of points. Now, I would appreciate if someone could explain me why in $\mathbb R^2$ it is necessary for the domain to be an open and convex set.

Answer (score 0):

I think i got it. The statement $$\oint_C \vec{F} \cdot d\vec{s}=0$$ for every closed path $C$ in $D$ is equivalent to the statement that $\vec{F}$ is a conservative vector field on an open connected region $D$ (We assume that $D$ is open, which means that for every point $P$ in $D$ there is a disk with center $P$ that lies entirely in $D$.) Now we assume that is connected, this means that any two points in $D$ can be joined by a path that lies in $D$ (then, it make sense to say that i've a line integral over $C\subset D$). Thus, $D$ is an open connected region.

Now, the stetament "$\vec{F}$ is a conservative vector field" is equivalent to "$\oint_C \vec{F} \cdot d\vec{s}=0$" on an oped connected region. But, the statement "$\vec{F}$ is a conservative vector field" is equivalent to "$\vec{\nabla} \times \vec{F}=0$" on an open convex region (every open convex set is open connected).

Again, the statement "$\vec{\nabla} \times \vec{F}=0$" is equivalent to "$D_kf_i(x)=D_if_k(x)$" (where $D_if_k(x)=\frac{\partial f_k}{\partial x_i}$ and every $f_k$ is the components of $\vec{F}$) on an open convex set. The conditions for this equivalence are necessary on an open connected set. But is necessary and sufficient on an open convex set, because is required for the construction of a potential $\phi$ such that $\vec{\nabla} \phi = \vec{F}.$